# How to efficiently apply conditional string methods to split a dataframe column in two?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm cleaning some data and want to conditionally split a column whose values are separated by a newline. (e.g., 3t10\n5b12) These data exist in either column_a or column_b, with the other being NaN. (For reference, columns are qualification_a_group or qualification_b_group. A person(row) can only be in one.)

Aside from the qualification columns, there is also a final and semi_final column (with the same type of data). I was able to split those using the attached code, but need to use a condition for selecting the qualification column that is not nan. I have tried the second chunk of code below but this only yields if column_a is not null.

```
'''
# This works
final_split = combined['final'].str.split("\n", n=1, expand=True)
combined['final_tops'] = final_split[0]
combined['final_zones'] = final_split[1]
'''

'''
# This only works for when qualification_a != nan
q1_split = combined['qualification_a'].str.split("\n", n=1, expand=True)
q2_split = combined['qualification_b'].str.split("\n", n=1, expand=True)

combined['qualification_tops'] = q1_split[0].where(q1_split[0] != np.nan, 
other=q2_split[0])
combined['qualification_zones'] = q1_split[1].where(q1_split[0] != 
np.nan, other=q2_split[1])
'''
```

I believe this is due to the method not iterating each row, and that I need to use a for-loop to parse the qualification column unlike the final and semi_final. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong initially, and if so to the former what is the most efficient/pythonic way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: np.where instead of df.where

```
''''
combined['qualification_tops'] = np.where(q1_split[0].isnull(), q2_split[0], q1_split[0])
combined['qualification_zones'] = np.where(q1_split[0].isnull(), q2_split[1], q1_split[1])
''''
```